# Saving a URL generated PDF physically on sever

Tags: java, pdf, pdf-generation

I have a URL Id which generates a PDF .. I want to save that pdf file somehwere in my server using java . The PDF is getting generated dynamically so its not available on server .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code snippets:

```
URL pdfUrl = new URL("http://www.website.com/pdf_location.pdf");
ReadableByteChannel rbc = Channels.newChannel(pdfUrl.openStream());
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("file.pdf");
fos.getChannel().transferFrom(rbc, 0, 1 << 24);
```

Replace `http://www.website.com/pdf_location.pdf` with actual PDF URL. Replace `file.pdf` with name and path of your PDF file.